# How to avoid sending getMany query after selecting item in ReferenceInput Select Input [React-Admin V4]

Tags: react-admin

I'm using ReferenceInput with SelectInput, and i noticed that a getMany query will be send once i change select input value, i know it's default behavior from [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceInput.html#usage). i just don't need it, getList query and filter is enough for me, and getMany will cause error since the props 'enableGetChoices' and 'filter' didn't apply to getMany query. Can i simply disable it?

```js
<SimpleForm>
  <ReferenceInput
    sort={{ field: '', order: 'ASC' }}
    source="productId"
    reference="products"
  >
    <SelectInput optionText="productName" validate={[required()]} />
  </ReferenceInput>
  <FormDataConsumer>
    {({ formData, ...rest }) => {
      return (
        <ReferenceInput
          enableGetChoices={({ productId }) =>
            productId !== undefined && productId !== null
          }
          filter={{ productId: formData.productId }}
          source="optionId"
          reference="product_options"
        >
          <SelectInput
            label="Option"
            optionText="optionName"
            resettable
            validate={[required()]}
          />{' '}
          // Every time i change select value will trigger getMany query which i
          don't need and will cause error since enableGetChoices and filter
          did't apply.
        </ReferenceInput>
      );
    }}
  </FormDataConsumer>
</SimpleForm>
```

I'm looking for a way to disable getMany query after changing select input value, or apply enableGetChoices and filter props to getMany query if there is no way to disable it.

Thanks a lot and Best wishes!